# ffmpeg converting from mkv to mp4 without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to switch container from mkv to mp4 via this command:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -vcodec copy 1.mp4
```

this is the simplest command that I found when converting from mkv container to mp4 without re-encoding. The output stated otherwise (if I am not mistaken)

This is a small screen shot of the the output:

[image: FFmpeg Screenshot]

Where it said Stream Mapping, #0:0 (264 (native)) -> 264 (libx264)). Does this mean that it's re-encoding from x264 to libx264? What Did I do wrong?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: image link -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/44I9Z.jpg

Comment: In the future, note that FFmpeg questions belong on SuperUser.com.

Comment: The console output is text. It can be copied and pasted. No need for an image of some of the text. It would be like writing an email to someone, then taking a screenshot of just half of it, and then sending that.

Answer (score 59):

problem solved, specify the audio codec solve my problem...

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy 1.mp4
```

Comment: Just use `-c copy` instead of `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`.

Comment: Also note the -i argument must come BEFORE the -vcodec and -acodec arguments.

Answer (score 11):

Remuxing containers, e.g. MKV or AVI to MP4, with FFmpeg will only keep a single – it tries to choose the *best* one available – audio and video stream from the input file in the output file. This can be avoided by providing [`-map 0`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Matroska files frequently contain subtitles in a format not supported in MOV/MPEG containers by FFmpeg, esp. SRT/Subrip or ASS/SSA. They can either simply be dropped with `-sn` or be converted to a native format like `mov_text`. (You could also [*burn* hard subtitles into a video stream with filters](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo).)

Sometimes, adding missing information by using heuristics might help. This is activated with `-find_stream_info`, but I am not sure whether this should be used by default.

I shall assume that built configuration is not important to know (`-hide_banner`) and only serious problems should be logged to the console ([`-loglevel warning`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Generic-options), alternatively: `quiet` | `panic` | `fatal` | `error` | `warning` | `info` (*default*) | `verbose` | `debug` | `trace`).

Therefore, a rather universal conversion command looks like this:

```sh
$ ffmpeg -find_stream_info -i input.mkv \
         -map 0 -codec copy -codec:s mov_text output.mp4 \
         -hide_banner -loglevel warning; \
  rm input.mkv
```

For batch processing multiple files on a Windows box within `cmd` and overwriting existing files (`-y`), use `for`:

```
FOR /r %F IN (*.mkv) DO (@ffmpeg \
  -find_stream_info -i "%F" \
  -map 0 -codec copy -codec:s mov_text "%~pnF.mp4" \
  -hide_banner -loglevel warning -y)
```

Comment: One addition, your suggested command replaces (adds) all stream names with `SoundHandler`. This can be prevented by `-metadata:s:a:0 handler_name='' -empty_hdlr_name 1`. This will tell ffmpeg to not use the default 'SoundHandler'  name for streams, instead a empty string is used, which means take the default/normal stream name.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Windows and want to convert a directory  of MKV files, throw this batch file in the same directory and execute it:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%F IN (*.mkv) DO (
    ffmpeg -i %%~nF.mkv -acodec copy -vcodec copy %%~nF.mp4
)
```

**Some context in case anyone else is facing the same:**

I'd previously recorded my desktop using OBS; the mkv file wasn't accepted by Sony Vegas. I ran the above batch which called *ffmpeg* on each of the captures and the resultant MP4s were accepted by Sony Vegas.

Answer (score -2):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input_file_name.mkv output_file_name.mp4
```

It converts to mp4 but it making a bigger size. :)

Comment: this is worse than remuxing